# Software used for solving demands of different functions

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, soft-question

I'm currently doing some research on demand systems and have been experimenting with different underlying utility functions which will generate different systems of demands. However I've been doing most of this work with pen and paper and often it seems that a machine would be better regarding solving some routine questions regarding marshallian and hicksian demands.

Is there a software which I can use to solve Lagrangian where I can obtain a specific functional form for Marshallian demands and Hicksian demands?

Comment: Maple is a good program due to its ease of use, I would take a look at that. Although I imagine this question will bring about even better programs!

Comment: Most stuff you want to do with Maple can also be done with Maxima afaik. The upshot is that it is free, the downside is that searching for examples is harder given its unfortunate name.